# Unable to generate logs in pcf UI console

Tags: log4j, pcf

I have configured loggers in my spring boot project using log4j.properties file. I am able generate loggers on my local but not able to generate loggers in pcf UI console.

I have mentioned the file name as below.
log4j.appender.fileAppender.File=demoApplication.log

Could anyone please help me to provide path of PCF in this log4j properties file so that I can able generate logs on PCF UI console.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this problem too.
This is my solution (put it in your .properties files and you can change the pattern as you like):

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS} | %m%n
```

I found it in pivotal.io and it works for me.